# About mocking frameworks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermockito

I am using `powermock` and with this I have several questions.

1. Do we need to modify our code in case we found(at later stage) it's not testable with `powermock` or `mockito` or any other testing framework?
   i.e. should we stop writing static/private methods some framework can't test it(I know `powermock` has capability for testing these kind of methods)
2. While mocking/spying an object should the actual method be called? i.e. I check it by keeping a debug point in method call, should the execution go to debug point?

Please help me in understanding these things.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Untestable / poorly testable code is mostly a sign of poor design, so yes you should change your code. Massively static methods / state is a code smell which means poor design and leads at the end to higher maintenance efforts.
Private methods should usually be tested within their public callers because they are just helpers. In my opinion private methods should never be tested directly because they may change at anytime via refactoring as the public interface of your class should be some sort of stable.

2.) When you mock, the target method/object should not be called. While spying should call the spied method/object

Answer (score 0):

I was brought into a team that had a giant legacy system, but they were adding new class/methods to it. These classes and methods would touch up to 10 DAO/DAL. However, these DAO/DAL had been up and running for 20+ years and had very few failures. So their behavior was pretty much expected. Using mocks in this case worked out really well, I could write purely unit tests for the new code, and mock all the DAOs to return objects/ or exceptions to check our boundary scenarios.

Mocks are great for when you have to access Data bases, make connections over the internet, or have a particularly large class you don't want to instantiate to only call one method from. If you have a class that requires many objects in its constructor(which would each need to be instantiated), but really you just need to get Class.CanRetry() (which would either return true or false), a mock would work lovely in this instance.

A hammer is a great tool, but it won't help you unclog a toilet... at least well. Mocks are a great tool to know how to use, but there is a time and place for them.

Please refer to these two great articles for more information on how/when to use mocks:

[When to Mock](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html)

[Mocks aren't stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) (bit of a longer read, but great information)

In regards to your second question this next article will give you the best understanding of the difference between all the different types of "test doubles" which includes mock objects, Test spys, dummy objects, etc...
[Agile Engineering: Test Doubles](http://www.agile-engineering.net/2011/11/test-doubles-with-mockito.html)